# Improving APIs that call 3rd party APIs

Tags: design, architecture, programming-practices

So I'm designing the backend of a platform that often calls other 3rd party APIs.
The issues I've noticed were latency issues (sometimes the calls were fast, others a bit slow >15s) and I'm wondering how to handle that.

I mostly get resources (and download them every single time). Is there a better practice to have better performances?

Edit: Thank you for your feedback and your answers. I'll try to describe my problem better.

I currently designed an API that fetches releases and sources from GitHub, on demand.

Now, sometimes these items/elements can be very heavy, and can impact performance and response delays, and it's very hard to anticipate when those resources are reachable and when they aren't (in the rare cases that a repo has moved, or if a release has been deleted or renamed).

I've considered using caching but again, I don't know how to handle the cases where the supposedly existing content doesn't exist anymore.

I hope these precisions provide more clarity to my question and I'm sorry for any misunderstandings.

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to make it reasonably answerable here.  Sounds like you need to do some troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

The classic approach to handling sluggish external accesses is caching. You might have heard of that :-)

Caching does not help in every case (for example, if you access a resource for the first time, and that access is slow) but it can help quite a bit on average.

Prefetching as @JonasH suggested may be used in combination with on-demand caching for resources that you know in advance will be needed.

However, one drawback about caches is that they can become stale (like any information). You need to think about a cache management policy that keeps a good amount of data in the cache to make it effective while evicting entries that may be stale. Of course, anything that is needed in a transactional manner can't be cached.

Answer (score 2):

Premature optimization may be the root of all evil. But once you have identified that there is a problem that needs optimizing, the next step is to profile everything.

Work out which calls are slow, and why. Are you downloading megabytes of data just to pick one field out of it? Is there data that should be cached locally?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend a great deal on your specific case, and that is not described in any great detail.

One approach that may be applicable for some cases is to use a separate background service that periodically pulls data from the third party and stores it locally. This has the advantage of consistent access times, and that your service will still stay up even if the third party service goes down. This is obviously not applicable if you need real time data, or the third party do not provide any way to replicate the data.